# excel sql aliases

Tags: sql, excel, alias

I can not use an alias with the temporary table. The query initially filters the records by year, then groups the quantities according to the `SKU` field and finally finds the field that has the largest amount.

Is there a way to simplify the query?

```
SELECT P_SKU
FROM 
 ( SELECT SKU AS P_SKU, COUNT(Q) AS TOT_Q 
   FROM [Transazioni$]
   WHERE Anno = 2014 
   GROUP BY SKU ) 
WHERE 
  TOT_Q = SELECT MAX(TOT_Q) FROM 
                              ( SELECT COUNT(Q) AS TOT_Q 
                                FROM [Transazioni$]
                                WHERE Anno = 2014 
                                GROUP BY SKU)
```

**Sample data:**

```
    SKU      Q   Anno  
 ---------- --- ------ 
  at.1-029   1   2014  
  at.1-077   1   2014  
  at.1-122   1   2014  
  at.1-077   1   2014  
  at.1-021   1   2014  
  at.1-032   1   2014  
  at.2-144   1   2014  
  at.2-034   1   2014  
  at.1-021   1   2014  
  at.1-122   1   2014  
  at.2-015   1   2014  
  at.v-034   1   2015  
  at.1-077   1   2015  
  at.1-077   1   2015  
  at.1-032   1   2015  
  at.1-122   1   2015  
  at.1-122   1   2015
```

Comment: can you please clarify ` I can not use an alias with the temporary table`? Why not? What is the objective?

Comment: also what data types are these fields?

Answer (score 0):

Double check that the data types of `Q` and `Ano` are numeric in the table design.

Then try this variation of your query:

```
SELECT P_SKU
FROM 
 ( SELECT SKU AS P_SKU, COUNT(Q) AS TOT_Q 
   FROM [mydata]
   WHERE Anno = 2014 
   GROUP BY SKU ) a
WHERE 
  a.TOT_Q = (SELECT MAX(TOT_Q) FROM 
                              ( SELECT COUNT(Q) AS TOT_Q 
                                FROM [mydata]
                                WHERE Anno = 2014 
                                GROUP BY SKU) b )
```

...Note the aliases `a` and `b` and how they are used to refer to values coming from the subqueries, as well as the extra set of brackets.

[image: img]